# convert self joining update to merge

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have below update statement which is performing very slow to be converted to merge. I'm trying to change the below statement to merge statement. any suggestions

```
UPDATE CLASS CL
SET (PARENT_CLS_TITLE,
PARENT_SECTION_FLAG,
PARENT_ACADEMIC_CODE,
PARENT_CLASS_FL
) =
(select  
PARENT.CLASS_TITLE  PARENT_CLASS_TITLE
,PARENT.SECTION_FLAG  PARENT_SECTION_FLAG
,PARENT.ACADEMIC_CODE PARENT_ACADEMIC_CODE
,PARENT.CLASS_FL PARENT_CLASS_FL
from CLASS CHILD
, CLASS PARENT 
where CHILD.PARENT_TERM_NUMBER = PARENT.TERM_CODE || '|' ||PARENT.CLASS_NUMBER
AND CL.CRSE_ID=CHILD.CRSE_ID
AND CL.CRSE_OFFER_NUM=CHILD.CRSE_OFFER_NUM
AND CL.TERM_CODE=CHILD.TERM_CODE
AND CL.SESSION_CODE=CHILD.SESSION_CODE
AND CL.CLS_SECTION_CODE=CHILD.CLS_SECTION_CODE)
```

Definition and index on the table. This is the only stuff present on table no other constraints etc

```
  CREATE TABLE CLASS
  (
  CRSE_ID VARCHAR2(255),
  CRSE_OFFER_NUM VARCHAR2(255),
  TERM_CODE VARCHAR2(255),
  SESSION_CODE VARCHAR2(255),
  CLS_SECTION_CODE VARCHAR2(255),
  CLASS_NUMBER VARCHAR2(255),
  PARENT_TERM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(255),
  CLASS_TITLE VARCHAR2(255),
  SECTION_FLAG VARCHAR2(1),
  ACADEMIC_CODE VARCHAR2(255),
  CLASS_FL      VARCHAR2(1),
  PARENT_CLS_TITLE VARCHAR2(255),
  PARENT_SECTION_FLAG VARCHAR2(1),
  PARENT_ACADEMIC_CODE VARCHAR2(255),
  PARENT_CLASS_FL VARCHAR2(1)
  );

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_CLASS ON CLASS
  (CRSE_ID, CRSE_OFFER_NUM, TERM_CODE, SESSION_CODE, CLS_SECTION_CODE);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of the CLASS table, including all data types, keys (primary, unique, and foreign), and indexes. Thanks.

Comment: And, depending on the answer to Bob's question, it is possible that you may not need a MERGE statement (although for this type of problem MERGE is often the best choice). You may, for example, be able to update your table directly through the join. The time savings, if any are possible, will come from rewriting the statement, not necessarily from using MERGE over UPDATE. (But, again, that depends on what keys you may have on the CLASS table.)

Comment: I have provided the script from toad. Thanks for looking into this. That table has lot of rows and update is executing forever.

Comment: I don't understand. Your table `CLASS` has a column `PARENT_CLS_TITLE`, and in the `UPDATE` statement you take another column, `PARENT.CLS_TITLE`, and give it the **alias** `PARENT_CLS_TITLE`? When that name is used elsewhere, what does it refer to - the column that had that name to begin with, or the different column that you gave that alias to?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I was able to follow the logic correctly, but I believe the statement below is logically equivalent to your original one. Give it a try and let us know.

```
UPDATE CLASS CL
SET ( PARENT_CLS_TITLE    ,
      PARENT_SECTION_FLAG ,
      PARENT_ACADEMIC_CODE,
      PARENT_CLASS_FL
    ) =
    ( select CLASS_TITLE  ,
             SECTION_FLAG ,
             ACADEMIC_CODE,
             CLASS_FL
      from   CLASS 
      where  CL.PARENT_TERM_NUMBER = TERM_CODE || '|' || CLASS_NUMBER
    )
;
```

Of course, what you posted does not guarantee that the subquery returns a single row. If it returns more than one row, the update will fail. (This was true for your original statement, too.) Perhaps in your data it is true that the subquery returns only one row - it's just that it doesn't follow necessarily from the information you presented.